# JavaIO Input variable value issues

Tags: java, java-io

```
 public static void main(String[]someVariableName) throws IOException{
    int Actinium = 89;
    int Ac = Actinium;
    String element //tried multiple variable data types
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an element");
    element = in.next();
    System.out.println(element);
```

I'm trying to make a program that when a user inputs an elemt's name or abbreviation, the program outputs the atomic number.  In this example, I only have Actinium, which has an atomic number of 89.  When I run the program, the output is only the literal input.

Comment: .... what do you expect? you put whatever the user inputs a in a variable, then print that variable... why would it print ANYTHING else?

Comment: Computers are generally very stupid. You have to tell them in really small details how to do complicated stuff. In this case, you have to tell the computer the exact steps that it has to take to get from the user input to the atomic number - what it has to read and where to put it, what it has to check and what to do if the check succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs are not correlated to any data structure, plus you are not doing any relation in the first two sentences where you think you are. In the first two statements you are giving the same value to two variables: "Actinium", and "Ac".

First thing to do: Create an inline data structure to correlate the data you will input with the data you are querying. For this case I'll recommend a HashMap because querying a Map has a time efficiency of O(1) (which probably you don't what it means but it's important in bigger applications)

```
 public static void main(String[]someVariableName) throws IOException{ 

 HashMap<String, Integer> hm=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 hm.put("hydrogen", 1);
 hm.put("helium", 2);
 ...

 System.out.println("Please enter an element");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String name=br.readLine();
 System.out.println(hm.get(name));
```

Now you are creating a relation between Strings (chains of characters) and Integers, and if the String introduced in the input is found in the relational map, it will return is correspondent numeric value.

Comment: Here, too. The OP wants to get from element name to its atomic number, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a mapping of atomic numbers with it names.It means you require a key value pair in which key will be atomic number and its value will be element name.

In java we use hashmap for this.

```
    public static void main(String[]someVariableName) throws IOException{

        Map<String,Integer> elementMap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        elementMap.put("Actinium",89);  //Actinium becomes key and 89 its value
        String element //tried multiple variable data types
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an element");
        element = in.next();
        System.out.println(elementMap.get(element));//gets the value for particular key
}
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: The OP is asking to get from the element name to its atomic number, not the other way around. Also, there are variables there that you don't use.

Comment: ...and the unneeded variables?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still learning Java, and I guess I got a little ahead of myself thinking I could do this with what I already know.